# What does ‘Rollie Plain’ mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

source: song **The Box** - Roddy Ricch

> I just made the **Rollie plain** like a landing-strip

Answer (score 1):

A "Rollie" is slang for a *Rolex watch*.

The word "plain" is not part of the noun with the above - it is an adjective, and part of a *simile* "plain like a landing strip".

A landing strip (for aircraft) is a flat surface, so I presume it means "plain" in the sense of having no features. Quite how that relates to a watch, I can't explain, sorry - I'm no rapper.

Comment: Perhaps "made the Rollie" is "obtained a Rolex watch", and then "plain like a landing-strip" is "easily".

Comment: Considering the line before this one (*'she suckin dick'*) the landing strip could also refer to the style of pubic hair, with a similar meaning.

Comment: @WeatherVane I'd agree with other definitions of "plain" if you could apply that to the landing-strip metaphor. How is a landing strip "easy"?

Comment: Only because a landing-strip is obvious, so a bit weak.